# exchange server 5.5 stops responding

Tags: exchange

From last couple of weeks I am getting connection problem with my in-house company exchange server 5.5 running on windows 2003. It has been working fine from last 5 years. but from few weeks it is loosing connection with other outlook clients. I have to restart my exchange server to make it work. This happens few times in a week. It looses connection somewhere between 7PM to 8AM as when I come in office. I find this problem, while it leave office it works fine.

We have not installed any updates or software since last more than 2 years.

What could be the reason for stop working?

Comment: First off, are there any error messages in the event log? Are you running out of disk space? Have you done any troubleshooting at all that you can post? The downvote is for the lack of information and a consequently badly formatted question. I should also point out - Exchange 5.5? It came out in 1997. Microsoft doesn't support it at all any more. Exchange has shipped 4 versions - 2000, 2003, 2007 and 2010 since then. You REALLY should be looking at upgrading.

Comment: ...does Exchange 5.5 even *run* on Windows Server 2003?!?

Comment: -1 for running completely insanely obsolete software.

Comment: Just as an off guess, I'd say it's getting bogged down serving requests when people come into the office. Why you're running 5.5 is beyond me, but hey, if that's how you want to roll...

Comment: @Massimo No, it doesn't run on 2003 [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164323(EXCHG.65).aspx)

Comment: I wonder how he did get it to run at all, then... the dreadful words "in-place O.S. upgrade" are coming to my mind, and it's *not* a pleasant thought at all.

Comment: You can get it to run but, you shouldn't and its certainly not supported

Comment: thanks DriftPeasant for helping me a layperson. I checked the log file and find the problem. Can you post that in question  so I accept your answer. then I will tell the problem which I find in event log.  I am not administrator. I have to handle this server in my administrator's absence. as I told clearing in my question I am layperson. who made mistake to ask for help on wrong forum(server faults) where most appreciate negative voting and criticizing rather than helping. anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Holocryptic. I don't know How but it is running Ms Exchange 5.5 administrator with exchange 6.5.8 version on windows server 2003 small business server. I just find :) It is antique server :D almost 14 years old :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am very thankful to all those people who spent some time in reading my question and start criticizing by giving negative votes to question, rather than providing bit help to a person who know nothing about servers.

I specially say thanks to  Driftpeasant who pointed me to right direction to scrutinize the problem. This community is for everyone including beginners, novice (not only for big giants).

Problem in event logs, which I find is.

Exchange store 'First Storage Group\Mailbox Store (XXX)': The current physical size of this database (the .edb file and the .stm file) is 32 GB. This database has exceeded the size limit of 30 GB. However, the logical free space in this database has not yet been evaluated. Therefore, it is possible that this database contains enough free space to bring its logical size below the maximum size limit.
    If the logical database size exceeds the maximum size limit, it will be dismounted on a regular basis.

Now atleast I know what is a problem.

here is the [Problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/01eed052-9ada-47dc-90b5-68d99c5c5b69)
and
here is the [Solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998066%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

> What could be the reason for stop working?

…

> We have not installed any updates or software since last more than 2 years.

Asked and Answered: You have neglected your environment for at least 2 years - You should expect it to be falling apart.
Server environments DO NOT continue to just run forever, despite what we admins like to say in our smoke- and whisky-filled poker games: They require love and attention to ensure that they keep operating.

Running Exchange 5.5 (which I know is past its support life) on Win2k3 (which I'm also pretty sure is past its support life - SP2 may have some time left on the death clock) is a recipe for disaster.  The best advice anyone can give you is "Start planning your migration off this obsolete technology. ***NOW***."

---

If you really have your heart set on troubleshooting this mess I would suggest checking your system logs for information about the problem.  What you have described ("losing connection with other outlook clients") is so generic that I can't give you any better guidance, but if you find something relevant in your logs it might point to something that people can help you with.
Bear in mind however that Exchange 5.5 is so ancient (*1997!*) that most of the knowledge pool for it has been drained as people moved on to newer, better releases of Exchange.  There simply may not be anyone around who remembers enough about this software to help you.

Comment: I remember many things about it. Although I *really* wish I didn't...

Comment: We all try to block out the painful parts of our childhood. For me it's SCO.

Comment: I do understand what you mean by knowledge pool which has been drain. but dear every server have same way of loging. ever problem which you face can be find in event log. atleast now I know. whether if it is windows server NT or 2000 or what ever. Its all about how dedicate you are to help or criticize.